# netty channel and thread and eventLoop

Tags: netty

Please illuminate the relation among: **request, thread, eventloop, server channel and client channel**, when netty server and netty client are connected to make a proxy. Before I started, I thought for every request, netty server will acquire a worker thread from `eventloop`, and also a `channel` (bound to a worker thread, with limited object ids from a thread pool) to handle this inbound message, and send it to an outbound `channel` which comes from the netty client. Thereafter, the possible server `channel` is limited, while the client `channel` is unlimited (because the outbound port is randomly chosen). However, my observation is that:

1. both inbound channel and outbound channel are not limited.
2. sometimes different requests share the same inbound channel,
   sometimes don't.

when tutorials talk about using netty as a proxy, they always say the same eventloop used in server (`Serverbootstrap`) could be used to create client (`bootstrap`) to save threads overloads. What does this mean? when a client and server share the same eventloop, what do they share in essence? I am interested in this is because when clients are running in an async way, I don't know how to return a response message to its origin channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you asked multiple questions, I will try to answer all of these...

1) The limits of inbound and outbound channels need to be implemented by your self or you relay on the limit that is put in place by the OS that you use (which is most of the times the number of file-descriptors that can be opened per process).

2) A Channel represents a connections, so depending on the protocol that is used multiple requests / responses may share the same connection. This is for example possible with HTTP keep-alive which is the default for HTTP/1.1

Sharing the same EventLoop for the server and client allows to handle both with the same Thread which means you can transfer data between both without context-switch. This is especially important if you build something like a proxy.